# how to open up app by a command in the terminal just for once

Tags: command-line

recently I have been relying on the Linux terminal, to do pretty much anything, but I came across a problem, basically when I type in the terminal "brave" which actually opens the brave browser, the command keeps running, and if I tried to cancel it so I can use the terminal the browser closes, therefore, I want some sort of command that opens the app once and it doesn't block the terminal, sorry if I couldn't explain this better.